# Disable option in dropdown list based on selection in other list

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have the following code

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('select option').prop("disabled", false);
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val() +     "]").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

And then have 3 dropdown lists

```
<select name="vote1" id="vote1">
<option value="player1">Player1</option>
<option value="player2">Player2</option>
<option value="player3">Player3</option>
<option value="player4">Player3</option>
</select>
<select name="vote2" id="vote2">
<option value="player1">Player1</option>
<option value="player2">Player2</option>
<option value="player3">Player3</option>
<option value="player4">Player3</option>
</select>
<select name="vote3" id="vote3">
<option value="player1">Player1</option>
<option value="player2">Player2</option>
<option value="player3">Player3</option>
<option value="player4">Player3</option>
</select>
```

With my code when you select 1 item it disables it in the dropdown list of the other two iteams, however if I then click on another option in another list, it enables the options in the others.

I want to be able to select the option in one dropdown list and it stays disabled in all the other dropdown lists until it is deselected.

Is this possible?

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dannymh/y9tpgdwc/)

Comment: @Regent can you please assist me in figuring out how it would be accomplished? I am completely stuck with where to go now with my jscript

Comment: You could loop over each `select` each time one changes, and disable the options (the same way you have done above) - [have a look here](http://jsfiddle.net/sqy1n6n3/) (you'll want to cache the select collection)

Comment: @Dannymh you can save previous selected `option` and on change enable not all options, but only required ones. Something like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9tpgdwc/1/).

Comment: @billyonecan that works exactly as desired, did you want to put that in as a full answer rather than comment so I can accept it and upvote?

Comment: Thanks both, both options work perfectly, my sincerest gratitude! That has dug me out of the rabbit hole!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is pretty much the same as what you already had, except it loops over each select each time one changes, and disables the option selected in the other selects:

```
var $selects = $('select');

$selects.on('change', function() {

    // enable all options
    $selects.find('option').prop('disabled', false);

    // loop over each select, use its value to 
    // disable the options in the other selects
    $selects.each(function() {
       $selects.not(this)
               .find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]')
               .prop('disabled', true); 
    });

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqy1n6n3/1/)

Comment: Hi, how can i acheive the same for a table's dropdown, un-ordered lists instead of a select?

<div class="div1">
    <ul id="menu1">     
     <!-- <li><a href="#">Select2</a> -->
     <li><a href="#" id="disableOnNoMatch">Select2</a>
</ul>
     </li>
    </ul>

Comment: http://i569.photobucket.com/albums/ss138/raja777m/1_zpsjx6dsr2u.png
Here is the image.
I have similar dropdown below this table, i want to disable the options selected here.
Thanks in advance