# jQuery Mobile: disable selected option in other select menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have three select menus on my jQuery mobile page. If the user selects an option, I want this option to be disabled in the other select menus.

So far, I have managed to have the option disabled in the select element, but NOT in the options popup. The user can still select an option in the popup, but I want to prevent this.

Here comes my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/asvyY/57/

My code:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form>
            <select class="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
               <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>

            <select class="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
               <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>

            <select class="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
               <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$('.filter-menu').on('change', function() {
  var $changedSelect = $(this);
  var selectedId = $(this).val();

  $('.filter-menu').not($changedSelect).each(function() {
      $(this).find('option[value=' + selectedId + ']').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281916/disable-option-in-dropdown-list-based-on-selection-in-other-list

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/asvyY/59/

```
$('.filter-menu').on('change', function () {
            $('.filter-menu').find('option').prop('disabled', false);

           $('.filter-menu').each(function () {
               $('.filter-menu').not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
            });

            // rebuild select menus
            $('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
});
```

Rebuilding the select menus is necessary, as it is jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your phone, it makes the option physically unselectable (but not visibly)

```
$('select.filter-menu').not($changedSelect).each(function() {
    $(this).find('option[value="' + selectedId.toString() + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: please read my post more closely. I already managed to make the options physcially unselectable with the code I provided, but not visibly. I found the solution: $('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);

Comment: @Max tried a lot but this refresh thing didn cross my mind. Please post your answer. And also is that refresh required because of this implementation being on jQuery Mobile?

Comment: @Max ah my bad. Just another thing, using $('.filter-menu') instead of $('select.filter-menu') returns unwanted span elements (noticed this in the fiddle)